# How to sort a list containing a string alphabetically in rails view - rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4

i am new to rails and any help would be much appreciated.

- i am trying to sort my list by status, but i have string in code stating `"Pending"`
- i believe the error is prompting up because it can not place the status in order because i have a string

could one kindly advise the best way to go about sorting out a list in alphabetical order where by the list contains a string - thank you

> error message

```
comparison of String with nil failed
```

> jobseekerpg.html.erb

```
  <% @userj_applications.sort_by(&:status).each do |application| %>
    <%= link_to application.advert.title, userr_advert_path(application.advert.userr, application.advert) %> |
    <%= application.advert.city %> |
    <%= application.advert.category_country.name %> |
    <span>
      status:
      <% if application.status == nil %>
        <%= "Pending" %>
      <% else %>
        <%= application.status %>
      <% end %>
    </span> |
    applied: <%= application.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y") %><br>
  <% end %>
```

> static_controller.rb

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json

  def jobseekerpg
    @userj = Userj.find(current_userj)
    @userj_applications = @userj.forms
  end
 end
```

> my suggestion:

- i currently have a column named `status` in my table
- do i create another column in my table called `statusPending`
- make this as a hidden_field and assign it to pending `statusPending:Pending`
- so whenever an application status is `nill` i can use an `if & else statement` to call up `application.statusPending`
- but then i will not need to only sort by `status` , i will need to sort by `status` & `statusPending`

any advise or help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

> could one kindly advise the best way to go about sorting out a list in
>   alphabetical order where by the list contains a string - thank you

[Array#`sort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are getting that error when the sort_by method tries to compare a non null status with a null one. You could try to replace your statement:

```
@userj_applications.sort_by(&:status).each do |application|
```

with

```
@userj_applications.sort {|x,y| (x.status || '') <=> (y.status || '') }.each do |application|
```

This way nil values are treated as empty strings during sort.

Comment: BTW you can also replace `if application.status == nil` with `if application.status.nil?`

Answer (score 0):

```
stringList.sort!
```

The "array.sort!" should sort the list in-line.
Here are some ruby examples with blocks http://www.dotnetperls.com/sort-ruby